# Editing a Jquery Dialog CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am trying to edit my dialog box to have a transparent title bar that still shows an alternate 'X' to close it, but I am having issues here is my dialog css as of now:

```
/* Creates the 'X' used to close dialog */
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon 
{
    background-image: url("../Images/X.png") !important;
}  

/* Removes padding from title bar */
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar 
{
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
/* Remove title image and keep 'x' */
.ui-widget-header {
    background: transparent repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #F6A828;
    border: 1px solid #E78F08;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

As of now the transparent does not over ride the default color (adding `!important` doesn't change anything either) and the 'x' does not show up (though the default doesn't either). Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** This [link](http://jsbin.com/ikaho5/2/edit) shows the dialog box with my code. Notice how the background is not transparent when it runs. After playing around with it for a bit, I think the image is loading, but I just cannot see it (the colors are very similar) so I think once the title color is resolved that issue will go away as well

Comment: I think it works here: http://jsbin.com/ikaho5 try to put your code there, show us the problem

Comment: background: transparent repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish

```
background: transparent repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something i've done before, not removing the title image, but shrinking it to only contain the 'X'. and all done in the js when opening.

```
    $('#dialog').dialog();
var d = $('#dialog').dialog('open');

var titleBar = d.parent().find('div.ui-dialog-titlebar');
d.parent().find('span.ui-dialog-title').text('');
titleBar.css({
    'width' : '10px',
    'height' : '10px',
    'float' : 'right',
    'top' : '-35px'//only used to move x above dialog. not needed.
});
```